# How can i make calling multiple ListIterators more efficient?

Tags: java

Soo my question is if it is possible to simplify this chunk of code by perhaps using an array with the listnames (foodList, foodAmount, etc.) and than doing some kind of loop with the listnames (from said array) substituting their placeholders in the iterator?

here is the code:

```java
public static void writeFile() throws IOException{
    ListIterator<String> foodIterator = GrocerieList.foodList.listIterator(0);
    ListIterator<Integer> foodAmountIterator = GrocerieList.foodAmount.listIterator(0);
    ListIterator<String> drinkIterator = GrocerieList.drinkList.listIterator(0);
    ListIterator<Integer> drinkAmountIterator = GrocerieList.drinkAmount.listIterator(0);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/Users/c-mon/IdeaProjects/final/src/shoppingList.txt");

    // FOOD
    writer.write("foodList");
    writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    if(foodIterator.hasNext()){
        do{
            writer.write(foodIterator.next());
            writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        }while(foodIterator.hasNext());
    }else{
        writer.write("empty");
        writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    }

    writer.write("foodAmount");
    writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    if(foodAmountIterator.hasNext()){
        do{
            writer.write(foodAmountIterator.next() + "");
            writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        }while(foodAmountIterator.hasNext());
    }else{
        writer.write("empty");
        writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    }

    // DRINKS
    writer.write("drinkList");
    writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    if(drinkIterator.hasNext()){
        do{
            writer.write(drinkIterator.next());
            writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        }while(drinkIterator.hasNext());
    }else{
        writer.write("empty");
        writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    }

    writer.write("drinkAmount");
    writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    if(drinkAmountIterator.hasNext()){
        do{
            writer.write(drinkAmountIterator.next() + "");
            writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
        }while(drinkAmountIterator.hasNext());
    }else{
        writer.write("empty");
        writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

This is where the lists are declared

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class GrocerieList {

    static ArrayList<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> hygieneList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> drinkList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> otherList = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> foodAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> hygieneAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> drinkAmount = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> otherAmount = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void foodOutput (){
        ListIterator<String> foodListIterator = foodList.listIterator(0);
        ListIterator<Integer> foodAmountIterator = foodAmount.listIterator(0);

        if(foodListIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("\t" + "Food");
            do {
                System.out.println("\t" + foodAmountIterator.next() + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + foodListIterator.next());
            }while (foodListIterator.hasNext());
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\t" + "Food");
            System.out.println("\t" + "No food on your list");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    public static void drinkOutput (){
        ListIterator<String> drinkListIterator = drinkList.listIterator(0);
        ListIterator<Integer> drinkAmountIterator = drinkAmount.listIterator(0);

        if(drinkListIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("\t" + "Drinks");
            do {
                System.out.println("\t" + drinkAmountIterator.next() + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + drinkListIterator.next());
            }while (drinkListIterator.hasNext());
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\t" + "Drinks");
            System.out.println("\t" + "No drinks on your list");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    public static void hygieneOutput (){
        ListIterator<String> hygieneListIterator = hygieneList.listIterator(0);
        ListIterator<Integer> hygieneAmountIterator = hygieneAmount.listIterator(0);

        if(hygieneListIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("\t" + "Hygiene");
            do {
                System.out.println("\t" + hygieneAmountIterator.next() + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + hygieneListIterator.next());
            }while (hygieneListIterator.hasNext());
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\t" + "Hygiene");
            System.out.println("\t" + "No hygiene products on your list");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    public static void otherOutput (){
        ListIterator<String> otherListIterator = otherList.listIterator(0);
        ListIterator<Integer> otherAmountIterator = otherAmount.listIterator(0);

        if(otherListIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("\t" + "Other products");
            do {
                System.out.println("\t" + otherAmountIterator.next() + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + otherListIterator.next());
            }while (otherListIterator.hasNext());
            System.out.println(" ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("\t" + "Other Products");
            System.out.println("\t" + "No other products on your list");
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }

    public static void rewe (){
        System.out.println("########################################");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Here is your REWE shopping list!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Qty" + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + "Product");
        System.out.println(" ");
        foodOutput();
        drinkOutput();
        hygieneOutput();
        otherOutput();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }
    public static void lidl (){
        System.out.println("########################################");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Here is your LIDL shopping list!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Qty" + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + "Product");
        System.out.println(" ");
        drinkOutput();
        foodOutput();
        otherOutput();
        hygieneOutput();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }
    public static void edeka (){
        System.out.println("########################################");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Here is your EDEKA shopping list!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Qty" + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + "Product");
        System.out.println(" ");
        foodOutput();
        hygieneOutput();
        otherOutput();
        drinkOutput();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }
    public static void aldi (){
        System.out.println("########################################");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Here is your ALDI shopping list!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Qty" + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + "Product");
        System.out.println(" ");
        drinkOutput();
        foodOutput();
        hygieneOutput();
        otherOutput();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }
    public static void kaufland (){
        System.out.println("########################################");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Here is your KAUFLAND shopping list!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Qty" + "\t\t" + "\t--\t" + "\t\t" + "Product");
        System.out.println(" ");
        foodOutput();
        otherOutput();
        drinkOutput();
        hygieneOutput();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("########################################");
    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you add where the lists are declared?

Comment: Yup - easier to understand now? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```java
private static <T> String arrayListToString(ArrayList<T> list){
    if (list.size() == 0){
        return "empty\n";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(T t : list){
        sb.append(list instanceof ArrayList<String> ? t : Integer.toString(t));
        sb.append('\n');
    }
}

public static void writeFile() throws IOException{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("/Users/c-mon/IdeaProjects/final/src/shoppingList.txt");

    writer.write("foodList\n");
    writer.write(arrayListToString(GrocerieList.foodList));
    writer.write("foodAmount\n");
    writer.write(arrayListToString(GrocerieList.foodAmount));
    writer.write("drinkList\n");
    writer.write(arrayListToString(GrocerieList.drinkList));
    writer.write("drinkAmount\n");
    writer.write(arrayListToString(GrocerieList.drinkAmount));

    writer.close();
}
```